# Mouse left clicks not registering on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, double-click

A couple of days ago my mouse stopped registering 70% of my left clicks.

It takes several clicks in order to select or click on anything. It took me about 4 clicks just to click on this text box, for example.

I have had this mouse, a Shogun Bros Ballista Mk-1, for a good few years now and this is the first time it has happened.

I have tried plugging it into a different USB port, but it failed to do anything.

Is this a mechanical issue, a driver issue or something else entirely?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is most likely a mechanical issue... You should try a different mouse on the same computer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you know...I didn't think of doing that. I shall have to find one somewhere.